# Jsf Netbeans, Hibernate, Get Session Factory cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, session, netbeans

Im doing a JSF Project using Netbeans for school. I got a simple Problem. My Code is:
`

```
public class PlayerData{

   private Player pl;
   private HibernateUtil helper;
   private Session session;

    public void addMember(){
       pl=new Player ("Example")
       session=helper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(pl);
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close()

}

}
```

`

My Error = 
cannot find symbol 
     symbol:method getSessionFactory()
     location: variable helper of type HibernateUtil

Comment: Does `HibernateUtil` _have_ a `getSessionFactory()` method?

Comment: As much as i know, yes. They used it in many diffrent Solutions i read before.

Comment: Make sure you have imported the correct `HibernateUtil`.

Answer (score 0):

I know project for school is probably now finished but many others are reading this question and need the answer. Solution is: You need to make your own HibernateUtil class. How? Answer is [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) and [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#04).